# How can I make scroll lock?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to make a website like tesla.com and I saw in source scroll bar lock I have a html code:

```
<div id="cont-1" class="full-container">
   <p> This is container 1 </p>
</div>
<div id="cont-2" class="full-container">
   <p> This is container 2 </p>
</div>
<div id="cont-3" class="full-container">
   <p> This is container 3 </p>
</div>
```

and style.css

```
.full-container { width: 100%; height: 100vh; }
```

I want to make in here when I'm scrolling down or up scroll is should be locked in cont-3 or cont-2 how can I make this?

Sample website: https://www.tesla.com/

Comment: You can lookup the concept of "scrolljacking" in your favourite search engine, it should give you pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into the newer CSS property [`scroll-snap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap). Without this it's going to be a good chunk of JS scripting.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
  flex: none;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: none;
  line-height: 256px;
  font-size: 128px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 100%;
}

.container > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #87EA87;
}

.container > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #87CCEA;
}
```

```html
<div class="container y proximity-scroll-snapping" dir="ltr">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ShashankVivek yeah you're right! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 2):

you can do this simply by using the fullpage.js library in javascript

This definitely helps you

See the below demo link:

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html

Comment: Thank you for answer I learned 2 way to do this first fullpage.js or css scroll snap.

Answer (score 1):

That's a scroll-snap.

If you don't particularly care about IE11 support, you can try this

```css
html {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

/* your element */
.full-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/#article-header-id-5) for the complete reference.

You can also use a JS library like [scroll-snap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-snap) (but I prefer the CSS one personally)